# Ler o nome ou tipo de um arquivo remoto aberto com "fopen"

Tags: php

No meu script em PHP tenho uma linha que lê um arquivo com `fopen`, usando a url `"https://api.modarchive.org/downloads.php?moduleid=".$i` (`$i` é um contador de um *loop*) onde eu salvo o arquivo na variavel `$file`, e eu quero salvá-lo no meu computador usando `file_put_contents()`, só que para isso, eu preciso definir o caminho o qual eu quero salvar, incluindo a extensão do arquivo.

O problema é que não dá pra saber a extensão do arquivo baixado só pela URL, então não dá pra usar `pathinfo()`, nem `explode`, nem nenhum tipo de função que use o caminho do arquivo como parâmetro, eu consigo realmente baixar o arquivo, mas definindo uma extensão padrão, ou não definindo.

O problema é que os arquivos originais tem extensões e tipos que variam.

O código que eu tento rodar atualmente é esse:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i ++){
    $file = fopen("https://api.modarchive.org/downloads.php?moduleid=".$i, 'r');
    file_put_contents("mods/mod".$i.".extensaodoarquivo", $file);
}
```

Existe alguma função que retorne o nome ou a extensão do arquivo, talvez passando como parâmetro o arquivo em si, ao invés de uma *string* representando o caminho dele, ou alguma solução melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solução mais simples, o `$http_response_header`:

A váriável `$http_response_header` é de grande ajuda no URL da sua pergunta.

Quando você usa `fopen()` em recursos remotos, ela é populada automaticamente com o cabeçalho das requisições.

Para ver o formato dos dados, basta isso:

```
$file = fopen("https://api.modarchive.org/downloads.php?moduleid=".$i, 'r');
var_dump($http_response_header);
```

Uma linha é de especial interesse para nós:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=nomedoarquivo.it
```

Como o nome já vem listado, basta iterar o array retornado, para localizar a linha desejada, e dela extrair o nome:

```
$file = fopen("https://api.modarchive.org/downloads.php?moduleid=".$i, 'r');
$filename = '';
foreach( $http_response_header as $header ) {
    if( strtolower( substr( $header, 0, 20 ) ) === "content-disposition:" ) {
        $filename = substr( strstr( $header, '=' ), 1 );
    }
}

echo 'o nome original é: '.$filename
```

caso o `header` desejado exista, `$filename` estará populado com o nome original.

### Outras possibilidades:

Uma possível solução se não tivéssemos o nome nos cabeçalhos, seria a função

```
mime_content_type( $file )
```

Ela vai retornar o `mime-type` do arquivo fazendo uma análise do arquivo com base no arquivo `magic.mime`.

O formato do retorno é esse:

```
image/gif
image/png
application/x-7z-compressed
... etc ...
```

Na própria documentação tem algumas funções de exemplo para fazer um `array` de extensões e tipos com facilidade.

**Importante:** para um melhor aproveitamento de performance e banda, você pode testar o arquivo depois de recebido para depois renomeá-lo, evitando dois acessos remotos desnecessariamente.

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mime-content-type.php

Alternativamente você pode usar funções `fileinfo`:

```
<?php
  $fi = new finfo( FILEINFO_MIME,'/usr/share/file/magic' );
  $mime_type = $fi->buffer( file_get_contents($file) );
?>
```

Manual:

> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.fileinfo.php

Ambas funções se baseiam no arquivo `mime.magic`, que comumente é disponível em servidores Linux, e também distribuido com PHP se precisar em outros sistemas.

O `mime.magic` contém alguns mapas de posições e bytes estratégicos, que servem para caracterizar os arquivos pelo seu conteúdo real.

Comment: acho que nem precisa mais, achei essa função get_headers() que a posição [7] me retorna o nome do arquivo e a extensão,eu posso usar isso pra pegar a extensão do arquivo sem problemas

Comment: tem coisa melhor: var_dump($http_response_header); que é o que eu tou pondo na resposta

Comment: O ideal é o loop da resposta, pois nada garante que a ordem e quantidade dos headers seja a mesma em todas as chamadas. 
Funcionou belezinha o código da pergunta, teste aqui: http://files.box.net.br/file.htm?i=7  (Troque o i pra ver o nome mudando)